# Connect to Azure CDN folder with SAS token

Tags: c#, azure, cdn

I have AzureBlobService.cs:

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

namespace AzureBlob.API.Service
{
    public class AzureBlobService
    {
        BlobServiceClient _blobClient;
        BlobContainerClient _containerClient;
        string azureConnectionString = "<Primary Connection String>";
        public AzureBlobService()
        {
            _blobClient = new BlobServiceClient(azureConnectionString);
            _containerClient = _blobClient.GetBlobContainerClient("apiimages");
        }

        public async Task<List<Azure.Response<BlobContentInfo>>> UploadFiles(List<IFormFile> files)
        {

            var azureResponse = new List<Azure.Response<BlobContentInfo>>();
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    file.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    var client = await _containerClient.UploadBlobAsync(fileName, memoryStream, default);
                    azureResponse.Add(client);
                }
            };

            return azureResponse;
        }

        public async Task<List<BlobItem>> GetUploadedBlobs()
        {
            var items = new List<BlobItem>();
            var uploadedFiles = _containerClient.GetBlobsAsync();
            await foreach (BlobItem file in uploadedFiles)
            {
                items.Add(file);
            }

            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

How I can change this code for connecting to azure cdn folder using SAS token?

Answer (score 0):

> How I can change this code for connecting to the Azure CDN folder using the SAS token?

To use **`SAS token`** instead of the connection string you can follow this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-dotnet-get-started?tabs=sas-token#authorize-access-and-connect-to-blob-storage) it will help you to connect storage account with SAS token.

You can try the below code to connect the storage account using the SAS token for uploading files and retrieving uploaded blobs.

**Code:**

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;


namespace AzureBlob.API.Service
{
    public class AzureBlobService
    {
        BlobServiceClient _blobClient;
        BlobContainerClient _containerClient;
        public AzureBlobService()
        {
            var sasToken = "<Your SAS-token without ?>";
            String blobUri ="https://<yourcdnendpoint>.azureedge.net";
            _blobClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri($"{blobUri}?{sasToken}"), null);
            _containerClient = _blobClient.GetBlobContainerClient("apiimages");
        }

        public async Task<List<Azure.Response<BlobContentInfo>>> UploadFiles(List<IFormFile> files)
        {

            var azureResponse = new List<Azure.Response<BlobContentInfo>>();
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    file.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    var client = await _containerClient.UploadBlobAsync(fileName, memoryStream, default);
                    azureResponse.Add(client);
                }
            };

            return azureResponse;
        }

        public async Task<List<BlobItem>> GetUploadedBlobs()
        {
            var items = new List<BlobItem>();
            var uploadedFiles = _containerClient.GetBlobsAsync();
            await foreach (BlobItem file in uploadedFiles)
            {
                items.Add(file);
            }

            return items;
        }
    }
}
```